# How to move file based on column name in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have 500 .xls files in my IN folder..In that folder i have two different set of files.
For (e.g) Some of the file having one extract column "Package Name", others file won't have.
so now i want to move with "Package Name" column file into some separate folder through unix. thanks

Comment: You will first need something to handle the XLS format, and I doubt a shell is the environment of choice for that. If you can change the format (maybe with a batch converter) CSV would be easy to read, and both XLSX and the open document formats would be doable

Comment: i am using this cmd...but it won't copy my destination path grep -rl --null --include '*.xls' Package . | xargs -0r cp -t /my path

Comment: You know this will filter on files that do not contain Package anywhere rather than only in the header, right? Anyway to debug your command add `echo` before `cp` and check if the generated commands are correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Perl module [Spreadsheet::Read](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Spreadsheet-Read/Read.pm) to parse spreadsheets. On Ubuntu you have to install the module with.

```
apt-get install libspreadsheet-read-perl
```

The following code is a very simple grep for spreadsheets:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $book = ReadData ($ARGV[1]);
my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::row ($book->[1], 1);

for my $cel (@row)
{
  exit 0 if $cel eq $ARGV[0];
}
exit 1;
```

If the search string is in the first row of the spreadsheet, the program returns with 0 and otherwise with 1.

I have used the following spreadsheet for testing.

[image: Example spreadsheet]

With the above program you can loop through your files.

```
for f in *.xlsx; do
  if spreadsheet-grep 'Package Name' "$f"; then
    mv "$f" /tmp/.
  fi
done
```